# javascript dialog box is not appearing on button click using js,ajax,php

Tags: php, ajax, jquery-ui-dialog, dialog, jquery-selectbox

Hi i have dialog box which should open on button click and will display message 'It works' inside dialog box. But i dont know why after button click the dialog box is not appearing.Thank you.

Here is my js code:

```
function getaddwidget()
    {
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax/dashboard.php",
        dataType : 'json',
        cache: false,
        data: {'aktion' : 'add-new-widget'},
        success: function(data){
            $('#addwidget').html(data.html);

        },
        error: function(data){
            alert('error');
            //$('#news').html(data.html);
        }
      });
  } 



    $(function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      show: {
        effect: "blind",
        duration: 1000
      },
      hide: {
        effect: "explode",
        duration: 1000
      }
    });

    $('#addwidget .butt-rahmen').live('click', function(){
            if($(this).attr('id') == 'addwidgetId')  
      $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
      getaddwidget();
    });
  });
```

dashboard.php

```
if($param['aktion'] == 'add-new-widget')
{     


    $html = '<table width="538" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
            <tr>
                <td id="addwidget">
                   <div id="dialog">
                            <p>IT WORKS!!!</p>
                    </div>                  
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>';

    $return = array(
            'status' => 1,
            'html'  => $html
        );

    echo json_encode($return);
    die();
}
```

Comment: anyone know the solution ?